# Most efficient way to apply function on the subset of data (alternatives to ddply)

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, dplyr, plyr

I have quite substantial data set where value of different objects is reported over time. Furthermore, value itself can be measured multiple times per year. I'am just interested in  **taking plain average of the valuations** for one object in a given year. My problem is that, due to the size of the data it takes quite a while to apply function on chosen subsets. Are there any more efficient ways to do that? I read somewhere that using `data.table` should speed up the process but with my toy example that is not really the case.

Toy example (+ benchmarking):

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

time_taken_df = c()
time_taken_dt = c()

test_data <- data.frame(id = round(runif(1000, 1,10), 0),
                        Value = round(runif(1000, 10, 50), 0),
                        Value_Year = round(runif(1000, 1999, 2010), 0))

for (i in 1:100){

  #Data Frame
  test_data <- as.data.frame(test_data)

  start_time_df <- Sys.time()

  test_data <- test_data %>%
    ddply(.(id, Value_Year), mutate, new_val = mean(Value))

  end_time_df <- Sys.time()

  #Data Table
  test_data <- as.data.table(test_data)

  start_time_dt <- Sys.time()

  test_data <- test_data %>%
    ddply(.(id, Value_Year), mutate, new_val = mean(Value))

  end_time_dt <- Sys.time()

  #Results
  time_taken_df[i] <- end_time_df - start_time_df
  time_taken_dt[i] <- end_time_dt - start_time_dt
}


mean(time_taken_df)
mean(time_taken_dt)
```

Any suggestions how to achieve faster performance are welcome!

**Note:**

- I reduced actual valuation date to valuation year, to increase clarity of the example.
- Desired output is a **data.frame**, since there are other characteristics that are later used in the analysis.

Comment: You are not using `data.table` to group by and take the mean, you are merely using `plyr::ddply()` on a `data.table` which is not going to improve the performance.

Comment: You need to use data.table syntax: `test_data <- data.table(id = round(runif(1000, 1,10), 0), Value = round(runif(1000, 10, 50), 0), Value_Year = round(runif(1000, 1999, 2010), 0))
test_data[,mean(Value), by=c("id", "Value_Year")]`

Comment: Fair point, I will try to fix that and compare the results!

Comment: Or, if you want to add the mean to the dataset, without aggregation, you'd do `setDT(test_data)[, myAvg := mean(Value), by=.(id, Value_Year)]`.

Comment: I was no aware of the `setDT` function, looks pretty neat. Thank you for all of the suggestions.

Comment: @Imo the setDT is lightning fast `mean(time_taken_df)
[1] 1.357766` `mean(time_taken_dt)
[1] 0.003700418`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments by **Imo** and **user3293236** using `data.table` significantly improves the performance. Using:

```
setDT(test_data)[, myAvg := mean(Value), by=.(id, Value_Year)]
```

or simply if `test_data` is already a `data.table`:

```
data_table %>%
    [, myAvg := mean(Value), by=.(id, Value_Year)]
```

Comparison between `dplyr` and `data.table`

```
mean(time_taken_df)
[1] 1.357766 

mean(time_taken_dt) 
[1] 0.003700418
```